# Magento 2 : Why the Extensions installation process from admin is not same as in Magento 1?

Tags: magento2, admin, extensions, installation, package

This may be a small question but I am curious, why is the extension installation process from admin in Magento 2.x not same as in Magento 1.x  (viz. Paste extension key to install) ?

To be brief:

**In Magento 1**

> We can install an extension or package by simply Pasting the extension key.

**In Magento 2**

> For upgrade or update, we must use the same authentication keys that were used to install the Magento software.

1. **Why is the whole installation process different ?**
2. **Why is the extension installation process in Magento 2, linked to the authentication keys ?**

A brief answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2, the extension installer is a web interface for [composer](/questions/tagged/composer) and fetches extensions from the composer repository **repo.magento.com**. This repository also contains **paid extensions** from the marketplace and that's why you need your authentication keys: to determine which extensions you are allowed to install.

Comment: Useful and thanks, please answer "Why is the whole installation process different ?"

Comment: Because the old installation process would not work anymore since Magento is built with composer as package manager now.